# select pdf with fileDialog and open pdf javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf file using and input `type='file'`, and trying to open and display the selected file, when i open the file with a `filedialog` the browser won't let me get the full path of the file, and since the file is generated from another app the only way i have to get the path is to manually select the file.

Also i need to send this pdf using angular `$http` and store it on database. But i can do this using `formData` api.

i create a fiddle with what i have that is almost nothing cuz i'm really clueless on how to do this, is it possible to do it?
http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanPinzonM/xy087338/

any help is greatly aprecciated

code so far:

```
<div ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px;">
        <label for="importPdf">Import Pdf</label>
        <input name="importPdf" type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().handleFiles(this.files)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the angular:

```
var soccerApp = angular.module('App', []);

soccerApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {


$scope.handleFiles = function (files, tipoDeArchivo) {
    var file = files[0];
    //can i do this with a fileReader?
    // var reader = new FileReader();

   console.log(file);        
    var formData = new FormData();


    formData.append(file.name, file);

    // Send Pdf using angular  $http.post
  //  SavePdfToDatabase(formData);

     // Open the pdf file on a new window or an iframe or anything.
    //how can this be done?
    window.open(file);
};



  function onFileReadComplete(event) {
    $scope.ImportarArchivoDespiece(event.target.result);
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you hosting this on?  I am asking this because I believe a server side solution might be easier for this.

Comment: im hosting it on a windows server IIS